# Reason for horizontal scrollbar on web page

Tags: html, css, horizontal-scrolling

If someone could be so kind to help me identify why [this site](http://matereo.com) is showing an horizontal scrollbar, I'd appreciate it as I'm having a hard time finding it. This site uses Bootstrap, and custom CSS that includes overrides is in /css/main.css.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: on my computer I have both horizontal and vertical scrollbars.

Comment: vertical can happen, depending on the viewport resolution. what's yours? horizontal is not expected to happen in any case.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: actually vertical shouldn't happen either, if viewport > 375px. But  that I know where to adjust if necessary.

Comment: @j08691 I understand that, but it's just not practical to post code, because I don't know which zone of the code is causing the issue (I'd probably wouldn't be posting this if I knew that), and I'm not going to post the full website code. I'l be sure to contribute here with a clear definition of the problem and its mitigation, once I understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Firefox', Chrome's and I think even IE 11's developer tools, you can figure out which element is wider then the screen. In your case it's the `<div class="row top75 text-center main-row">`, which appears to be 30px wider. So take a look into your rules and you find

```
.row {
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
}
```

which is causing your problem with horizontal scrollbars. Remove it for this div and you should be good to go.

Comment: Yep that's it. Have to override Bootstrap's margin on that one. Thanks!